# How to find out I'm on the last page when querying Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, pagination, facebook-javascript-sdk

As an exercise I'm writing simple (and also as stateless as possible) client-side application (in React) displaying posts in feed of single Facebook entity. The application gets its data from Facebook Graph API.

I use Facebook JS SDK to query the following URL: `/<entity-id>/feed?limit=20&fields=...`

I have simple paging buttons ("previous" & "next"), which are querying paging URLs received in API response in `response.paging.previous` and  `response.paging.next` respectively.

The problem is **I don't know how to find out if I'm on the last page** to disable the "next" button correctly.

There are couple of things I tried, however I still don't get what I want.

**Option 1: Allow clicking "next" until there are no more data in response**

- Button gets disabled when `response.data.length == 0`.
- `paging` object contains `next` URL even when there are no more data to be received, so I can't check it before getting to page with no data.
- Problem is that when I get to that page, there is also no `paging` object included in `response`. As a result I can't use the "previous" button to get back to the last page with data.

**Option 2: Allow clicking "next" until I receive less data than query limit**

- Button gets disabled when `response.data.length < limit`.
- Works well for collections where `data.length % limit != 0`.
- Problem is in the opposite case, for example when there are 40 objects in the collection and I'm on the second page with limit 20, I can still click "next", but then I end up on page with no more objects, as mentioned in Option 1.

**Option 3: Remember URL of last request**

- Last request URL is stored into variable, and "previous" button works even in case when there are no `paging` data in `response`.
- Solves only the "you can't go back" problem.
- Doesn't solve the problem with correctly disabling the "next" button. It is still possible to click "next" on the last page with data and get to the empty page with no data.

**So the question is:**

How can I find out that I already received last items in collection and by clicking "next" I will get to invalid empty page?

- It seems weird to me that Graph API provides the `response.paging` URLs even on the beginning/end of the collection.
- For example if I have feed with 10 posts and I query with `limit 20`, I receive `response` with `data: Array[10]` and `paging` object with valid URLs in both `paging.previous` and `paging.next`, even though there are no "previous" and no "next" data.
- Querying those URLs results in `response` with empty `data` array and with no `paging` object, so I there is no way to get back in stateless application.
- Wouldn't it be better if there were no `paging.previous` on the beginning of the collection and no `paging.next` on the end of collection?

Comment: Additionally, I'm finding that `paging.next` never disappears, even at the end of the list, causing an infinite loop of requests. Seems one has to remember what the last `next` URL was and then break if it's the same?

Comment: @Matt That was pretty much one of issues I experienced in the past. Never had to work with FB API again though. Might be that specification changed so `next` item is always available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone seeing this - this is actually doable. I'm not sure if the Graph paging object previously had always returned a previous and next or if OP was making a mistake anywhere. However, I can confirm it will correctly return a previous/next when the data is able to go forward or backwards as you'd expect.

The below sample is from the Graph API paging documentation and shows the result set that is the first page of the collection.

```
"data": [
       *data returned*
],
"paging": {
  "cursors": {
    "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVGd3T1Rrek9UZAzROVGN3TlRNNE5Eb3hOVEV6TURnM09UTTIZD",
    "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVGd4TURBd09UazROVFk1T0RNM05Eb3hOVEV6TURreU5qQXoZD"
  },
  "next": "https://graph.intern.facebook.com/v2.11/1809938745705498/comments?access_token=valid_token_goes_here"
}
```

Notice the absence of a 'previous' property in the object. Merely checking if next or previous was present was enough for me to proceed to disable/hide buttons.

Comment: I didn't work with FB API since then, but if that's the case, it seems it finally makes sense. I'm sure in December 2016 it worked as I wrote - I even tested it on my own FB group, where I wrote 10 posts, and then queried its feed with limit 20, still received both `paging.previous` and `paging.next` URLs. It was really weird behaviour.

Comment: No problem. I figured that was the case. Thanks for responding back and clearing it up! :)

Answer (score 1):

By Graph API Cursor-based Pagination. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#cursors

There is no matching way to do it as you want, out of the box.
You should manage left records and your next button, separately of Graph API pagination. 
As a solution preload next page in addition to current.

Also saving previous cursor is bad practice:
"Don't store cursors. Cursors can quickly become invalid if items are added or deleted."

Comment: Regarding to saving cursors - what happens when I'm browsing a page and somebody deletes the record which is referenced by provided cursor? If I use that next URL, it will be invalid already. Is there any way out? For example how to return one page back in the middle of browsing?